# combine JSON object and JSON array to get another JSON object in Java

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have    `List<Person>` where its JSON output is like:

```
[{"name":"john","email":"john@email.com"},
{"name":"daniel","email":"daniel@email.com"},
{"name":"thomas","email":"thomas@email.com"}]
```

and a count of the persons where its JSON format is like: `{"number":3}`

How can I combine the above two to get the result:

```
{
"number":3,
"persons":[{"name":"john","email":"john@email.com"},
        {"name":"daniel","email":"daniel@email.com"},
        {"name":"thomas","email":"thomas@email.com"}]
}
```

my Java code  is jersey2 based JAX-RS application. to make more clear, I have a list of Person fetched from database and i also have an integer variable number. and combine the List and the integer variable to get above result in an efficient and robust way.

Comment: You can create a new POJO or use a Map

Comment: I do not want to create JSON using loops. what i want is if possible do this without using any loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a framework that already does conversion to JSON automatically, the easiest way would be to just return a new object.

```
public class Result {
  private int number;
  private List<Person> persons;

  //leaving creation of constructor to you
}
```

And then just instantiate that object and return it.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to map Object to json directly or want to convert json to object, you can use GSON library . this will give you more flexibility and control.

Download link - http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Tutorial link - http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/